# Jsoup: How to get all html between 2 header tags

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get all html between 2 h1 tags. Actual task is to break the html into frames(chapters) based of the h1(heading 1) tags.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: are you trying to get '<h1>abc</h1>' abc from it

Comment: I think he wants to get all the content to the next h1, so he can split the page by headlines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get and process all elements between two consecutive `h1` tags you can work on siblings. Here's some example code:

```
public static void h1s() {
  String html = "<html>" +
  "<head></head>" +
  "<body>" +
  "  <h1>title 1</h1>" +
  "  <p>hello 1</p>" +
  "  <table>" +
  "    <tr>" +
  "      <td>hello</td>" +
  "      <td>world</td>" +
  "      <td>1</td>" +
  "    </tr>" +
  "  </table>" +
  "  <h1>title 2</h1>" +
  "  <p>hello 2</p>" +
  "  <table>" +
  "    <tr>" +
  "      <td>hello</td>" +
  "      <td>world</td>" +
  "      <td>2</td>" +
  "    </tr>" +
  "  </table>" +
  "  <h1>title 3</h1>" +
  "  <p>hello 3</p>" +
  "  <table>" +
  "    <tr>" +
  "      <td>hello</td>" +
  "      <td>world</td>" +
  "      <td>3</td>" +
  "    </tr>" +
  "  </table>" +    
  "</body>" +
  "</html>";
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
  Element firstH1 = doc.select("h1").first();
  Elements siblings = firstH1.siblingElements();
  List<Element> elementsBetween = new ArrayList<Element>();
  for (int i = 1; i < siblings.size(); i++) {
    Element sibling = siblings.get(i);
    if (! "h1".equals(sibling.tagName()))
      elementsBetween.add(sibling);
    else {
      processElementsBetween(elementsBetween);
      elementsBetween.clear();
    }
  }
  if (! elementsBetween.isEmpty())
    processElementsBetween(elementsBetween);
}

private static void processElementsBetween(
    List<Element> elementsBetween) {
  System.out.println("---");
  for (Element element : elementsBetween) {
    System.out.println(element);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the heading name printed before and get the headings to come in order. Is there any good place where i can look for more examples on jsoup.

Comment: I assume that you want to print the heading text rather than its name (the name of an H1 heading is always "H1"). So, to do that you just print `sibling.ownText()` before calling `processElementsBetween(elementsBetween);`. I'm not sure what you mean by "get the headings to come in order". JSoup documentation: [cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/), and [apidocs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/)

Comment: This will not work for text not being part of a tag, like `<h1/>this<h1/>`. It seems to be a hole in jsoup concept.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know Jsoup that good, but a straight forward approach could look like this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Document document = Jsoup.parse("<html><body>" +
            "<h1>First</h1><p>text text text</p>" +
            "<h1>Second</h1>more text" +
            "</body></html>");

        List<List<Node>> articles = new ArrayList<List<Node>>();
        List<Node> currentArticle = null;

        for(Node node : document.getElementsByTag("body").get(0).childNodes()){
            if(node.outerHtml().startsWith("<h1>")){
                currentArticle = new ArrayList<Node>();
                articles.add(currentArticle);
            }

            currentArticle.add(node);
        }

        for(List<Node> article : articles){
            for(Node node : article){
                System.out.println(node);
            }
            System.out.println("------- new page ---------");
        }

    }

}
```

Do you know the structure of the articles and is it always the same? What do you want to do with the articles? Have you considered splitting them on the client side? This would be an easy jQuery Job.

Comment: EDIT: changed element to node, to be more generic and capture text nodex without surrounding tags.

Comment: No structure is not always the same. Actually these are all word documents converted to filtered HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over the elements between consecutive `<h>` elements seems to be fine, except one thing. Text not belonging to any tag, like in `<h1/>this<h1/>`. To workaround this I implemented `splitElemText` function to get this text. First split whole parent element using this method. Then except the element, process the suitable entry from the splitted text. Remove calls to `htmlToText` if you want raw html.

```
/** Splits the text of the element <code>elem</code> by the children
  * tags.
  * @return An array of size <code>c+1</code>, where <copde>c</code>
  * is the number of child elements.
  * <p>Text after <code>n</code>th element is found in <code>[n+1]</code>.
  */
public static String[] splitElemText(Element elem)
{
  int c = elem.children().size();
  String as[] = new String[c + 1];
  String sAll = elem.html();
  int iBeg = 0;
  int iChild = 0;
  for (Element ch : elem.children()) {
    String sChild = ch.outerHtml();
    int iEnd = sAll.indexOf(sChild, iBeg);
    if (iEnd < 0) { throw new RuntimeException("Tag " + sChild
                    +" not found in its parent: " + sAll);
    }
    as[iChild] = htmlToText(sAll.substring(iBeg, iEnd));
    iBeg = iEnd + sChild.length();
    iChild += 1;
  }
  as[iChild] = htmlToText(sAll.substring(iBeg));
  assert(iChild == c);
  return as;
}

public static String htmlToText(String sHtml)
{
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sHtml);
  return doc.text();
}
```