# Jsoup: Selecting HTML Between Different Classes

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to do something similar to: [Jsoup: How to get all html between 2 header tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534456/jsoup-how-to-get-all-html-between-2-header-tags)

However, it seems my code is avoiding plain text.
The site I'm parsing has code setup in such a way:

```
div class = "quoted-message"
     Response. Can contain images, text, etc.
div class = "quoted-message"
     Another response to another quoted message
```

Code Snippet used to handle the actual messages:

```
Element quote = msg.select(".quoted-message").first();
Boolean hasQuote = false;
Elements siblings = null;
siblings = quote.siblingElements();
createQuotePost(quote);
List<Element> elementsBetween = new ArrayList<Element>();
    for (int i = 1; i < siblings.size(); i++) {
        Element sibling = siblings.get(i);
        if (! "div.quoted-message".equals(sibling.tagName())) {
            elementsBetween.add(sibling);
            }

        else {
            Log.v("location", "Clear and Process");
            processElementsBetween(elementsBetween);
            elementsBetween.clear();
        }
    }
    if (! elementsBetween.isEmpty())
        processElementsBetween(elementsBetween);
```

This, however, does not seem to work as I want it to. The responses to the code do not have any special formatting to them (ie: sitting in a p tag). Using a bit of logging, I can see they aren't getting put into Elements siblings.
Siblings seems to just include line breaks and such.

Note: I've only tested this on small posts (simple one liners) to save on sifting through long pages of printouts.

Any suggestions on what to do?

EDIT:
Here is the HTML code snippet between 2 quoted-message divs:

```
    MESSAGE TO BE QUOTED
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    Hello quoted message
    <br />
    I am a response
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="quoted-message">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think one of the problems is you're asking for Elements and not Nodes. Text nodes are Nodes and not Elements.

Try this:

```
package grimbo.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<div class=quoted-message>message-1</div>\n    <br />\n    <br />\n    Hello quoted message\n    <br />\n    I am a response\n    <br />\n    <br />\n";
        html += "<div class=quoted-message>message-2</div>\n    <br />\n    <br />\n    Hello quoted message\n    <br />\n    I am a response\n    <br />\n    <br />\n";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        handleQuotedMessages(doc.select(".quoted-message"));
    }

    private static void handleQuotedMessages(Elements quotedMessages) {
        Element firstQuotedMessage = quotedMessages.first();
        List<Node> siblings = firstQuotedMessage.siblingNodes();
        List<Node> elementsBetween = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Element currentQuotedMessage = firstQuotedMessage;
        for (int i = 1; i < siblings.size(); i++) {
            Node sibling = siblings.get(i);

            // see if this Node is a quoted message
            if (!isQuotedMessage(sibling)) {
                elementsBetween.add(sibling);
            } else {
                createQuotePost(currentQuotedMessage, elementsBetween);
                currentQuotedMessage = (Element) sibling;
                elementsBetween.clear();
            }
        }
        if (!elementsBetween.isEmpty()) {
            createQuotePost(currentQuotedMessage, elementsBetween);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isQuotedMessage(Node node) {
        if (node instanceof Element) {
            Element el = (Element) node;
            return "div".equals(el.tagName()) && el.hasClass("quoted-message");
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static List<Element> filterElements(String tagName, List<Node> nodes) {
        List<Element> els = new ArrayList<Element>();
        for (Iterator<Node> it = nodes.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Node n = it.next();
            if (n instanceof Element) {
                Element el = (Element) n;
                if (el.tagName().equals(tagName)) {
                    els.add(el);
                }
            }
        }
        return els;
    }

    private static void createQuotePost(Element quote, List<Node> elementsBetween) {
        System.out.println("createQuotePost: " + quote);
        System.out.println("createQuotePost: " + elementsBetween);
        List<Element> imgs = filterElements("img", elementsBetween);
        // handle imgs
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great, however, is there an easy way to put the node back as an element? It will sometimes contain images/links and I have a method already setup to parse those out and would hate to recode it all.

Comment: So you only want to retain the raw text nodes in your `elementsBetween` List?

Comment: Well, I have a method (we'll call it CreateMessage) that requires an Element. Inside the method I use a .select("img") to pull the urls for all the images out into an array. Then when displaying the message, it uses that list to put the images back.

Same for urls and such. If its a big pain, I could just recode it to take a string and work off that though.

Comment: I think I understand. If `<img>`s are special then in the `createQuotePost` method you can iterate the `elementsBetween` List and handle `<img>`s specially. The problem with using `.select("img")` would be that the `<img>`s aren't descendants of the quoted message `<div>`, so you would have to do something else. Personally, a simple loop of `elementsBetween` would be more than adequate (which I've added to the answer).