# Scraping data from html <body> element

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am using JSoup, which is an HTML parser library in pure Java, to pull and parse pure HTML pages (well, with very little JS) off the internet. So far, everything is working fine if the data I want to scrape is attached to a very verbose HTML element (like `<a href="....">` or `<span class="myclass myotherclass">` and so on), but I am lost as to how to get data that is attached to the body element in an efficient manner.

I can get the `<body>` tag easily in JSoup, but the text in this tag is usually a mess and its impossible to generalize what is inside it across the many web pages I need to scrape (around 250 or so). I'd like to know if the HTML tree is useful is this case if we have something like

```
<span class="myclass">...</span>
<p>something.....</p>
<!-- We are back in the body here according to chrome devtools -->
Data1: some data here...
Data2: more data here...
...

<!-- We get a similar pile of HTML here except with different data in the span and p tags -->
<span class="myclass">...</span>
<p>something.....</p>
<!-- We are back in the body here according to chrome devtools -->
Data1: some data here...
Data2: more data here...
```

So my question is how can I get at `Data*` efficiently here using the DOM tree, or maybe I am missing obvious in this problem statement, since I am not a web developer by any means, this is just a hobby project.

Some ideas I had: preprocess the HTML to put some sort of tag around these that I can easily pull using JSoup (like a `<span>` tag with a class). Another idea was to use XPath to get the exact path to that part of the document. However, it seems like both of these ideas require me to be able to get to the data in the first place.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534456/jsoup-how-to-get-all-html-between-2-header-tags

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing you doing, what I found it is better to mix the Jsoup with HTML cleaner, Basically you need HTML cleaner in order to get your dom tree and then you can use JSOP

Comment: Hey Alaa, HTMLCleaner has very sparse documentation. What cleaner properties would i set in order to get the text i want in the body? Should I set some transformations somehow?