# jsoup remove a class

Tags: android, jsoup

Using jsoup select i've managed to extract the following html.I'm trying to get all the html code between `<a id="dd_start"></a>` and `<a id="dd_end"></a>`.

I've used `obj.first().getElementsByClass("div.dd_outer").remove()` with no luck.
Any suggestions?

```
<div class="entry-content" itemprop="text"> 
<a id="dd_start"></a>
<p><a href="http://blablabla.com/2016/01/16/blablabla/icon-2/#main" rel="attachment wp-att-21"><img class="size-full wp-image-21501 aligncenter" src="http://blablabla.com/wp-content/uploads/16/01/google1.jpg" alt="google-icon" width="100%"></a></p> 
<p>blablabla.<br> <span id="more-21499"></span><br> blablabla.</p> 
<p>blablabla <a href="https://blablabla.com/blablabla" target="_blank">blablabla</a>. </p> 
<a id="dd_end"></a>
<div class="dd_outer">
 <div class="dd_inner">
   <div id="dd_ajax_float">
     <div class="dd_button_v">
     </div>
   </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure which part of the HTML you want to remove - could you clarify ? Something like `myDocument.select("div.dd_outer").first().remove()` should do the trick though.

Comment: ideally i would like to select everything between <a id="dd_start"></a> and <a id="dd_end"></a>

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6534456/4428462), you will need to adapt the answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for the snippet you posted. You might want to make some changes to handle edge cases, errors etc.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("input.html")));
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements section = new Elements();
    Element sibling = doc.getElementById("dd_start").nextElementSibling();
    do {
        section.add(sibling);
        sibling = sibling.nextElementSibling();
    } while(!sibling.id().equals("dd_end"));

    System.out.println(section);
}
```

As far as the question of removing a certain section, you can do this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.select("div.dd_outer").first().remove();
System.out.println(doc);
```

This will remove the section from your `Document` object. Mind the `first()` that is being called before `remove()`. This is important. You want to call the `remove()` of `Element` which is what `first()` returns. This will remove the element from the `parentNode` thus affecting the `Document` object. If you do not call `first()` and change it to this

```
doc.select("div.dd_outer").remove();
```

You will be calling the `remove()` of `Elements` which is what `select()` returns. This is just a collection (list wrapper of sorts). So if you call `remove()` you will be affecting the result of `select()` and not the `Document`. So if you try to print the `doc` variable, you will see that what you removed is still there.

Comment: Glad I could help. Have fun